# gitlab push failed after install Redmine in the same host

Tags: redmine, gitlab

I installed gitlab(5.2) on my server(Debian Squeeze x64) for a long time, and it works well, but after I installed Redmine(2.3.3) on the same server, I can not push my git copy to server:

Git client console shows:

```
remote: /home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:33:in `eval_gemfile': Gemfile syntax error: (Bundler::GemfileError)
remote: /home/git/gitlab/Gemfile:29: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
remote: gem 'gitlab-grack', '~> 1.0.0', require: 'grack'
remote:                                         ^
remote:         from /home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:9:in `evaluate'
remote:         from /home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:19:in `build'
remote:         from /home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
remote:         from /home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
remote:         from /home/git/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
```

And I installed Redmine following http://www.netnerdz.se/2013/01/installing-redmine-2-1-x-2-2-x-with-ruby-1-9-3-under-debian-squeeze/

I know nothing about Ruby and Gems, so please if any one can help.

Comment: describe please in what moment you get the error? it looks like gitlab start to use ruby 1.8.7 and fails with new hash syntax. It is very strange. Try to check the version of ruby in `/home/git/gitlab` with command `ruby -v`.

Comment: Hi, I get the error when I run 'git push' in one of my git working copy. I checked the ruby version: git@AY130524105440102eedZ:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux]. Thanks.

Comment: It is the ruby1.8 problem, I forgot I installed ruby1.8 from debian repository when I install redmine. I works fine after I ran "apt-get purge ruby1.8". Sorry for bother.

Answer (score 1):

It is the ruby1.8 problem, I forgot I installed ruby1.8 from debian repository when I install redmine. I works fine after I ran "apt-get purge ruby1.8". Sorry for bother.